# Stack keeps popping the same element

Tags: java, stack

I've written a method that fills a bitmap represented by a m x n matrix. What I'm trying to do is to push the initial pixel to a stack, then in a while loop pop an element from the stack, color it and push neighboring pixels if they are the same color as the initial color of the initial pixel.

```
public void fill(int x, int y, char c) {
    char tempColor = this.bitmap[y - 1][x - 1];
    Point currentPoint;

    Stack<Point> fillStack = new Stack<Point>();

    fillStack.push(new Point(x, y));

    do {
        currentPoint = fillStack.pop();
//      System.out.println(currentPoint.x + " " + currentPoint.y);
//      System.out.println("Current state of the stack:");
//      for (Point p: fillStack)
//          System.out.println(p.x + " " + p.y);
        this.bitmap[currentPoint.y - 1][currentPoint.x - 1] = c;
        if (currentPoint.y - 1 > 0 && this.bitmap[currentPoint.y - 2][currentPoint.x - 1] == tempColor) {
            fillStack.push(new Point(x, y - 1));
//          System.out.println("Pushing " + currentPoint.x + " " + (currentPoint.y - 1));
        }
        if (currentPoint.y - 1 < n - 1 && this.bitmap[currentPoint.y][currentPoint.x - 1] == tempColor) {
            fillStack.push(new Point(x, y + 1));
//          System.out.println("Pushing " + currentPoint.x + " " + (currentPoint.y + 1));
        }
        if (currentPoint.x - 1 > 0 && this.bitmap[currentPoint.y - 1][currentPoint.x - 2] == tempColor) {
            fillStack.push(new Point(x - 1, y));
//          System.out.println("Pushing " + (currentPoint.x - 1) + " " + currentPoint.y);
        }
        if (currentPoint.x - 1 < m - 1 && this.bitmap[currentPoint.y - 1][currentPoint.x] == tempColor) {
            fillStack.push(new Point(x + 1, y));    
//          System.out.println("Pushing " + (currentPoint.x + 1) + " " + currentPoint.y);
            }
        } while (!fillStack.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for a reason I can't seem to spot. The output (debugging lines uncommented) is as follows:

```
3 3
Current state of the stack:
Pushing 3 2
Pushing 3 4
Pushing 4 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
Pushing 4 2
Pushing 4 4
Pushing 5 3
4 3
Current state of the stack:
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
3 2
3 4
```

... and it goes on like this in an endless loop. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your print statements say one thing, your code does another! ;)

for example:

```
fillStack.push(new Point(x, y - 1));
System.out.println("Pushing " + currentPoint.x + " " + (currentPoint.y - 1));
```

See if you can spot the difference...

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe that I have been looking at this thing for an hour and couldn't see this. Thank you :D